# Imprimir arraylist java

Tags: java, arraylist

Mi problema es que trato de imprimir una lista que contiene una lista y esa otra lista contiene una más. Es un diseño Top-Down para crear campeonato-equipo-jugador. Al utilizar un iterator y un for obtengo como resultado : Campeonato(arroba)7d4991ad. Es un menú en el cual el caso uno es para agregar los campeonatos y el dos para imprimirlos

```
System.out.println("Digite el numero de campeonatos que desee crear: ");
int i = sc.nextInt();
for (int x = 0; x < i; x++){                
    System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del torneo: ");
    String nombre = sc.nextLine();
    sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Ingrese el anio del torneo: ");
    int anio = sc.nextInt();
    Campeonato campeonato = new Campeonato(nombre, anio);
    camp.add(campeonato);
    //  Equipo eqi = new Equipo(nombre, sede);
    //  eqi.Crearequip(campeonato);
}

break;

case 2:
    Iterator itera = camp.iterator();
    while (itera.hasNext()){
        Object obj = itera.next();
        Campeonato caam = (Campeonato) obj;
        System.out.println(caam);
    }
    /*  for(int y = 0; y < camp.size(); y++){
        System.out.println(camp.get(y));
    } */
    break;
```

Esta es mi clase Campeonato donde defino sus atributos y constructor:

```
public class Campeonato{
    private String nombre;
    private int anio;
    ArrayList <Equipo> equip = new ArrayList<Equipo>();

    public Campeonato (String nombre, int anio){
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.anio = anio;
        //equip.add(equi);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Por cada objeto debes implementar el método **toString**. Eso depende de lo que quieres que se muestre. Muy por encima:

```
public class Campeonato{

    // tus cosas...

    public String toString() {
        return new StringBuilder().append("nombre=").append(nombre).append(" año=").append(anio).toString();
    }
}
```

Pero qué exactamente quieres que se muestre depende de ti.

Haces lo mismo por cada una de las clases que se contengan en las listas y veras lo que quieres ver ;-)

Saludos